# make multiple targets

Tags: make

I have this Makefile:

```
P5.obj P5.sym: P5.asm
        lc3as P5.asm
```

I want the assembler to run if either P5.obj or P5.sym are out of date. However, deleting P5.sym does not cause it to be regenerated.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I assumed the `lc3as P5.asm` will generate files `P5.obj` and `P5.sym`. Assumed you try run `make`.)

The default target is the first target unless you don't specify it (depends on make-dialect).

For example:

```
# Makefile
a b:
    echo a > a
    echo b > b
```

If you run `make` both file `a` and `b` will be created. If you delete `b` and run `make`:

```
`a' is up to date.
```

because the `a` target is the default.

The general solution is to create a target with name `all` at begin of `Makefile`:

```
all: a b

a b:
   echo a > a
   echo b > b

.PHONY: all
```

In this case if you delete `b` the `make` will regenerate it (because the default target is `all` and its dependencies are `a` and `b`).

Comment: Yep, this was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Dependencies usually go after the name of the rule, though it's unclear to me from your question what the inputs are and what the output is. Assuming `lc3as P5.asm` produces `P5` as output (and depends on all of `P5.asm`, `P5.obj`, and `P5.sym`) the entry might look something like:

```
P5: P5.asm P5.obj P5.sym
        lc3as P5.asm
```